# why is my app not found in app drawer when I installed it successfully in adb?

Tags: macos, adb, wear-os

Before to start, I'm very new to coding.

I'm trying to install a beta wearOS apk in my Galaxy Watch 5, by using MacOS terminal. (homebrew+adb)
Install success message appear well in my terminal,

```
performing streamed install
success
```

but the apk itself doesn't appear in my galaxy watch.

What should I do?
I'd be very glad if youguys help me